# Check if an array contains values from a list and add list as columns

Tags: python, arrays, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a data_frame as below,

| Id | Col1 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | [["A", "B", "E", "F"]] |
| 2 | [["A", "D", "E"]] |

I have a list as ["A", "B", "C"]

I would like to add the elements in the list as columns and check if the exist in col1 or not. So my expected output will be like,

| Id | Col1 | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | [["A", "B", "E", "F"]] | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 2 | [["A", "D", "E"]] | 1 | 0 | 0 |

I tried the below code to check if **any** one of the values in the list exist in Col1 but not sure how to do that for **each** of the values in the list.

```
    list_exist = data_frame.withColumn("list",F.array([F.lit(i) for i in list]))\
                      .withColumn("list_exist",F.arrays_overlap(F.col("Col1"),F.col("list")))\       
                      .drop("list")
```

I'm new to PySpark so any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be achieved using a `list comprehension`.

```
ls = ["A", "B", "C"]
...
df = df.select('*', *[F.array_contains('col1', c).cast('int').alias(c) for c in ls])
```

Comment: Thank you. This is an addition to the question above, can I do a rlike for the list? not the exact match but if the letters in list contains in Col1?

Comment: rlike is more convenient to use expr. Try：`df = df.selectExpr('*', *[f'cast(exists(col1, x -> rlike(x, "{c}")) as int) as {c}' for c in ls])`